# add ajax to select filed of node add,but no values of the filed in form['status']['values']

Tags: ajax

I have a node type with field:Budget Items  field_budget_items  Entity Reference    Select list.

and I want add ajax when value change.
so the code is :

```
function camplus_pr_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if(isset($element['#field_name']) && $element['#field_name'] == 'field_budget_items') {
    $element['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_get_bi_mixable_amount_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'bi_warning',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    );
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function camplus_pr_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $forms = array('camplus_pr_range_settings_form','camplus_pr_roles_involved_settings_form');

    if(in_array($form_id, $forms)){
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'camplus_pr').'/camplus_pr.css');
  }

  if($form_id =='purchase_request_node_form'){
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'camplus_pr').'/camplus_pr.js');
    $form['bi_warning'] = array(
      '#markup' => '1.您不能跨部门预算<br/>2.该部门的为负值，不可选择 <br/>3.不能超额',
      '#weight' => -100,
      '#prefix' => '<div id="bi_warning" class="messages warning">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    $form['#validate'][] = 'purchase_request_node_form_validate';
  }

}
```

and the callback function:

```
function ajax_get_bi_mixable_amount_callback($form, &$form_state) {
    // $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    dpm($form_state['values']['field_budget_items'],**'why I can not get the choosed value** of BI?');
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#bi_warning', $html='<div id="bi_warning" class="messages warning">budget_nid-->This BI ---</div>');
    return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

why I can not get the choosed value?? thx

Comment: can you see the ajax image when changing options?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code.

Comment: hmm, just took a quick glance, I also don't see any glaring errors. One thing I would check is to dpm the $form in camplus_pr_form_alter and make sure your ajax property is attached properly. It might not be attached on the proper $delta of that element. Just a thought.